# How to save values between different postbacks in view state in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am stuck in a problem I am creating a 100 question online test. Every question has four radio buttons (options) I want to know that when I select the options How can I make the browser to remember selected values of each question when I press submit button. I want to get values on submit button? I am using two properties liek "CurrentPageNo" and "IncrementCount" to set/get its value using viewstate.
Here is my code:

```
public void NavigateRecords()
{
    //CurrentPageNo = 1;
    PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
    pds.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    pds.AllowPaging = true;
    pds.PageSize = 1;
    // Set the PagedDataSource's current page
    pds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPageNo;
    lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page No: " + (CurrentPageNo + 1).ToString() +
        " of "
        + pds.PageCount.ToString();
    btnPrev.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;
    btnNext.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;
    btnFirst.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;
    btnLast.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;
    btnSubmit.Visible = pds.IsLastPage;

    repeaterItems.DataSource = pds;
    repeaterItems.DataBind();
    SelectedValue = rblOptions.SelectedValue;
    Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    for (int j = 3; j < 7; j++)
    {
        values.Add(dt.Rows[IncrementCount][j].ToString(), dt.Columns[j].ToString());
    }

    //var options = repeaterItemsFindControl("rblOptions") as RadioButtonList;
    //options = new RadioButtonList();

    rblOptions.DataSource = values;
    rblOptions.DataTextField = "Key";
    rblOptions.DataValueField = "Value";
    rblOptions.DataBind();
    lblMsg.Text = rblOptions.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Use two browsers.  One for main page and open second when you press button.  The first page will contain the button pushed.

Comment: Do you really need them there and can’t store them in the session?

Comment: Whatsoever the way (either viewstate or sessoin) is I need the selected values of all questions on pressing submit button

Comment: I thought by default all Asp.net controls have viewstate and not lose data on postback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Session to store your answers. So create a `List` or class to put in that session.
Then on page load check if the session exists. If it does cast the session to it's original type.

```
List<string> Questions;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["questions"] != null)
    {
        Questions = Session["questions"] as List<string>;
    }
    else
    {
        Questions = new List<string>();
        Session["questions"] = Questions;
    }
}
```

Now you can add an answer to that session on a Button Click.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Questions.Add("Answer 1");

    Label1.Text = "There are " + Questions.Count() + " answers";
}
```

If you keep pressing `Button1` you will see that the amount of answers increases.

Comment: it would be also useful to explain where the session keeps its values (server memory) and if the website scales horizontally, it not guaranteed that the same request goes through the same server, and that will make lose all data between pages... Maybe point him to Memcache/Redis or to make things simple: a cookie with a json with `id`, and `answer` :)

Comment: Thanks. But what about retaining of values of radio button list. I am using Questions.Add(rblOptions.SelectedValue) in onselectedIndexchanged method of radio button list but on pressing submit button it giving me selected value of last attempted question why?

Comment: @WaqasQureshi, that depends on how you are setting the data to the RadioButtonList. Are you doing that in an IsPostBack check?

Comment: This saved my life. 'Hours and hours of literal labor.